# Schedule process in background for every 30 seconds in Blue Prism RPA

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I had created a process in Blue prism and scheduled it in background for every 1 minute, but now i want to reduce the scheduled time for 30 seconds. Whenever i enter a value under 1 minute it's considering 1 minute by default.

How can I schedule a process for every 30 seconds ?

Please guide me.

Comment: If you can't find a way to schedule it every 30 seconds, maybe add a loop in your process to make run twice and keep it scheduled for every minute

Answer (score 2):

Three methods:

1. You could use two identical schedules, one scheduled 30 seconds after the other.

   **Pros**: You get the desired functionality
   **Cons**: Significantly more difficult to maintain if significant changes have to be made.
2. Use an external scheduling tool to kick off the process using Blue Prism's command line switches every 30 seconds.

   **Pros:** You get the desired functionality. Depending on the amount of time you want to spend configuring it, you could spread the kickoffs over a number of runtime resources.
   **Cons**: Adds an additional layer of complexity and maintenance on top of the Blue Prism environment.
3. Configure the process itself to continuously run in a loop on a particular runtime resource.

   **Pros:** You get the desired functionality. Minimal maintenance effort required.
   **Cons:** Depending on the run mode of the business objects utilized in the process, the particular resource you choose will be locked up until the process is killed.